# Are there any HTML widgets for embedding Hudson results?

Tags: hudson

Because, if there are, I can't find them. Basically, I would love to be able to show the build history on another web page. Has this been done before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hudson provides rss feeds of build histories. Links are at the bottom of the build page and will look something like this: http://hudson.company.com/rssAll

Then you can use the Google AJAX Feed API: http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/wizards/dynamicfeed.html which will generate all the code for you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the RSS feeds mentioned by [Scobal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347408/are-there-any-html-widgets-for-embedding-hudson-results/2347462#2347462) there's also the [Hudson Remote access API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API), which seems easy enough to use..
It all depends on how much information you need and how much effort you're willing to put into it yourself.. From the looks of it implementing something simple won't take you more than 15 minutes.